# how to call function after every +5 in value?

Tags: php

Hello everyone please help me i want call function on every +5 value

php example

```
$value = $_GET['total_refer'];

i want call function on 5, 10, 15, 20

If($value == 5) // call function on if value = 5, 10, 15, 20
{
  // Call function
}
```

Please if you have any logic please say us.

Thankyou

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and then check with `%` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php or if you don't need the other numbers just `$i+=5`.

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you :)

Comment: Really basic structures are so hard? `<?php for ($i = 5; $i <= 20; $i += 5) echo "do something with {$i} <br>";
`

Comment: Actually, your question after editing is quite **different**. Guys answered you how to deal with modulo, as you asked in the context of iteration (`$i++`) but if you want to check if `$_GET` value is in some range, you should rather use another approach i.e. `if(in_array($value, [5,10,15,20]))`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Without for loop:

```php
if ($value >= 5 && $value <= 20 && $value % 5 == 0) {
  myFunc(); // change to function name
}
```

---

```php
for ($value = 0; $value <= 100; $value++) { // if using loop
  if ($value % 5 == 0 && $value != 0) {
    myfunc(); // change to function name
  }
} // do not use for loop if not needed :)
```

or

```php
for ($value = 5; $value <= 100; $value++) {
  if ($value % 5 == 0) {
    myfunc();
  }
}
```

<sup>middle: 0 and values that are not divisible by 5</sup>
finally, if no *middle* values are required, you can use just a loop with proper start, end, and step.

```
for ($value = 5; $value <= 20; $value += 5) {
  myFunc();
}
```